# DKIM validation fails only on Outlook

Tags: postfix, email-server, spam, dkim, failed

I'm configuring OpenDKIM to sign miltiple domains with the same key on Pstfix. I followed [this tutorial](https://shankerbalan.net/blog/signing-multiple-domains-with-the-same-opendkim-key/) with `s=mail` and `d=example.com`.

- SigningTable:

  ```
  *       mail._domainkey.example.com
  ```
- KeyTable:

  ```
  mail._domainkey.example.com        %:mail:/etc/opendkim/keys/default.private
  ```

My TXT DNS record is on the main domain (`example.com`). It works great when I send an email from `example.com` using my FROM address as: `anything@example.com`.

The problem is with other domains using my Postfix server. When I send an email using my FROM address as: `anything@example.net` (I configured DKIM, DMARC and SPF on `example.net`'s DNS zone) the DKIM signature is added but using `d=example.net`.

The DKIM signature failed only on Outlook.

> dkim=fail(signature did not verify)

It passes on Gmail (`DKIM:PASS`), and I get 10/10 on mail-tester.com.

Comment: As this was originally written it was really hard to understand the situation.

Comment: This is probably answerable when looking at the `diff` between the the 2 resulting copies. Send the same mail to both a known-good recipient and to one failing to verify.